# Как правильно реализовать связь многие ко многим?

Tags: postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы. Первая это пользователи `user` которые могут ссылаться на неограниченное число записей в `site`. Получается отношение *многие ко многим* когда каждый пользователь относится к множеству сайтов, а каждый сайт к множеству пользователей.
Как правильно оформлять такие связи в виде таблицы? Говорят нужно 3-ю таблицу создавать, но не понятно как именно. Буду очень признателен за маленький но наглядный пример. Спасибо.

```
CREATE TABLE user (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE site (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        src TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    CREATE TABLE user_to_site (
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            site_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT "FK_user_id" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
          REFERENCES "user" ("id"),
        CONSTRAINT "FK_site_id" FOREIGN KEY ("site_id")
          REFERENCES "site" ("id"),
    );
```

И добавить уникальный индекс:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "UI_user_to_site_site_id_user_id"
  ON "user_to_site"
  USING btree
  ("site_id", "user_id");
```

Comment: Наличие синтетического ключа в связующей таблице кажется избыточным - во всяком случае, я не вижу ему вменяемого применения. Первичным вполне может быть указанный уникальный индекс (или обратный - зависит от раскладки по видам запросов), а дополнительным - обратный, или одиночный по второму полю.

Comment: +С учётом коммента Akin-ы

Comment: + к комментарию @Akina; первичный ключ там может быть нужен разве что для хранения каких-то данных о каждой связи. Но в этом случае проще считать связь отдельной сущностью, а это уже несколько толще, чем голый many-to-many.

Comment: А не могли бы вы немного объяснить мне CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ... это что и для чего без нее не как нельзя?

Comment: @Pavel можно и без индекса, но тогда вы рискуете привязать к одному юзеру один и тот же сайт более чем один раз.

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer а не могли бы вы тогда объяснить как работает этот индекс?

Comment: @Pavel UNIQUE Указывает, что система должна контролировать повторяющиеся значения в таблице при создании индекса (если в таблице уже есть данные) и при каждом добавлении данных. Попытки вставить или изменить данные, при которых будет нарушена уникальность индекса, будут завершаться ошибкой. https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/sql-createindex